# Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify placeId

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am getting error **Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify placeId.**. I think, I have to use $scope.$boradcoast and $scope.$on to listen the function. In service.getDetails I am using placeId,When this function called placeId is not generated. But When **I use hard-coded placeId, It is not giving error**. So my question is how to handle this type of error?

**HTML**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' control='map.control' id="map-canvas">
  <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idkey="markers.id" coords="'coords'" >

  </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**Controller**

```
 function geocodePosition(pos){
     geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
     }, function(responses){
        if (responses && responses.length >0){ 
          //Here I am getting place_id, I will use this place Id in PlaceServiec to get details of places.             
          $scope.place_id=responses[0].place_id;            
        } 
     });



    var map=$scope.map.control.getGMap();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails({
      placeId: $scope.place_id
        //placeId: 'ChIJu5k40vkW0zsReGq7bjOzHxU'
    }, function(place, status){
      console.log('place='+place);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` `$scope.place_id` and `responses[0].place_id?`

Comment: I'd recommend double checking that your values are saved the way you expect them to be.